# Finding difference between date now and last comment

Tags: php

I want users to wait 9 minutes after their last comment. I have written this code. It works but do you think this is practical? Is there a simpler solution?

```
$now = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
$lastPost = new DateTime( '2016-01-08 13:16:59' );
$diff = $lastPost->diff( $now );

if ( $diff->format( '%Y-%m-%d %H' ) == '00-0-0 00' ) {
    if ( $diff->format( '%i' ) < 9 ) {
         echo $diff->format( '%i minuts left or ahead' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current time is easily obtained simply with `new DateTime()`, no need to specify any formatting (default is `now`). Also you don't need to format dates to compare strings because `DateTime` itself is comparable. All together:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$lastPostTime = new DateTime('2016-01-08 13:16:59');
$notEnabledBefore = lastPostTime->add(new DateInterval('PT9M'));

if (now < notEnabledBefore) {
    $timeToWait = notEnabledBefore->diff(now);
    echo $timeToWait->format('%i minutes left or ahead');
}
```